# create data structure out of json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is my JSON Array

```html
   const locationsPermissions = [{
    'id': '699af5c3-48fd-4e12-89f5-9ebc6654dd1c',
    'company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'user_id': 'b5dfdfce-956f-41c3-9fe6-7d3ba8641a38',
    'location_id': '70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20',
    'created_by': 'naveen',
    'updated_by': 'naveen',
    'created_at': '2020-08-11T05:33:05.783Z',
    'updated_at': '2020-08-11T05:33:05.783Z',
    'location.id': '70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20',
    'location.name': 'Binatone Site',
    'location.notes': 'test',
    'location.type_id': '78fe9d30-dfc2-40ad-9147-d0a854e43bd1',
    'location.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'location.address_id': '58ea401a-2613-4a81-821a-276abbd04a46',
    'location.container_id': null,
    'location.created_at': '2020-08-10T18:20:54.779Z',
    'location.updated_at': '2020-08-10T18:20:54.779Z',
    'location.created_by': null,
    'location.updated_by': null,
    'location.location_type.id': '78fe9d30-dfc2-40ad-9147-d0a854e43bd1',
    'location.location_type.container_id': null,
    'location.location_type.can_have_devices': false,
    'location.location_type.name': 'site',
    'location.location_type.is_address_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.is_location_map_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.created_at': '2020-08-10T18:19:07.739Z',
    'location.location_type.updated_at': '2020-08-10T18:19:07.739Z',
    'location.location_type.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241'
  },
  {
    'id': 'd88a35e6-8a37-453b-ba4c-9159e5fdaa9a',
    'company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'user_id': 'b5dfdfce-956f-41c3-9fe6-7d3ba8641a38',
    'location_id': '8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d',
    'created_by': 'naveen',
    'updated_by': 'naveen',
    'created_at': '2020-08-11T05:33:05.785Z',
    'updated_at': '2020-08-11T05:33:05.785Z',
    'location.id': '8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d',
    'location.name': 'Binatone Building',
    'location.notes': 'test',
    'location.type_id': '6bec2cf9-7fe1-4065-9e98-5943eeba3e69',
    'location.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'location.address_id': '53e83177-07c8-42c0-9745-e001ad4368d2',
    'location.container_id': '70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20',
    'location.created_at': '2020-08-10T18:21:42.888Z',
    'location.updated_at': '2020-08-10T18:21:42.888Z',
    'location.created_by': null,
    'location.updated_by': null,
    'location.location_type.id': '6bec2cf9-7fe1-4065-9e98-5943eeba3e69',
    'location.location_type.container_id': '78fe9d30-dfc2-40ad-9147-d0a854e43bd1',
    'location.location_type.can_have_devices': true,
    'location.location_type.name': 'building',
    'location.location_type.is_address_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.is_location_map_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.created_at': '2020-08-10T18:19:43.073Z',
    'location.location_type.updated_at': '2020-08-10T18:19:43.073Z',
    'location.location_type.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241'
  },
  {
    'id': 'ba4269c3-dd39-452e-97ee-e5040c6913d3',
    'company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'user_id': 'b5dfdfce-956f-41c3-9fe6-7d3ba8641a38',
    'location_id': 'a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47',
    'created_by': 'naveen',
    'updated_by': 'naveen',
    'created_at': '2020-08-11T09:01:52.083Z',
    'updated_at': '2020-08-11T09:01:52.083Z',
    'location.id': 'a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47',
    'location.name': 'Binatone Latest',
    'location.notes': 'test',
    'location.type_id': '6bec2cf9-7fe1-4065-9e98-5943eeba3e69',
    'location.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'location.address_id': '65fd90d6-9742-4e59-9438-f056ed58949f',
    'location.container_id': '70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20',
    'location.created_at': '2020-08-11T08:56:17.044Z',
    'location.updated_at': '2020-08-11T08:56:17.044Z',
    'location.created_by': null,
    'location.updated_by': null,
    'location.location_type.id': '6bec2cf9-7fe1-4065-9e98-5943eeba3e69',
    'location.location_type.container_id': '78fe9d30-dfc2-40ad-9147-d0a854e43bd1',
    'location.location_type.can_have_devices': true,
    'location.location_type.name': 'building',
    'location.location_type.is_address_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.is_location_map_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.created_at': '2020-08-10T18:19:43.073Z',
    'location.location_type.updated_at': '2020-08-10T18:19:43.073Z',
    'location.location_type.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241'
  },
  {
    'id': '48fc20c0-732d-4a60-a475-67c324181fcb',
    'company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'user_id': 'b5dfdfce-956f-41c3-9fe6-7d3ba8641a38',
    'location_id': '4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93',
    'created_by': 'naveen',
    'updated_by': 'naveen',
    'created_at': '2020-08-11T10:35:43.438Z',
    'updated_at': '2020-08-11T10:35:43.438Z',
    'location.id': '4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93',
    'location.name': 'Binatone Area',
    'location.notes': 'test',
    'location.type_id': 'ba1ee2bc-e301-48ce-8b83-9531931c2973',
    'location.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'location.address_id': '6a79823f-8904-47bc-9df7-0ddf0e78ceea',
    'location.container_id': '70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20',
    'location.created_at': '2020-08-11T10:34:01.420Z',
    'location.updated_at': '2020-08-11T10:34:01.420Z',
    'location.created_by': null,
    'location.updated_by': null,
    'location.location_type.id': 'ba1ee2bc-e301-48ce-8b83-9531931c2973',
    'location.location_type.container_id': '78fe9d30-dfc2-40ad-9147-d0a854e43bd1',
    'location.location_type.can_have_devices': true,
    'location.location_type.name': 'area',
    'location.location_type.is_address_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.is_location_map_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.created_at': '2020-08-11T08:52:10.263Z',
    'location.location_type.updated_at': '2020-08-11T08:52:10.263Z',
    'location.location_type.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241'
  },
  {
    'id': 'e7140a20-5639-4989-bbad-f509c32daf76',
    'company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'user_id': 'b5dfdfce-956f-41c3-9fe6-7d3ba8641a38',
    'location_id': 'dd962969-36ce-416a-a9c7-794cc20fb233',
    'created_by': 'naveen',
    'updated_by': 'naveen',
    'created_at': '2020-08-11T12:26:22.075Z',
    'updated_at': '2020-08-11T12:26:22.075Z',
    'location.id': 'dd962969-36ce-416a-a9c7-794cc20fb233',
    'location.name': 'Binatone Street',
    'location.notes': 'test',
    'location.type_id': '732a8981-b9d5-457a-a2ef-2dfafbfec92e',
    'location.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241',
    'location.address_id': '277f38bc-2a06-41b5-b483-6d22eaca4e89',
    'location.container_id': '4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93',
    'location.created_at': '2020-08-11T12:25:14.690Z',
    'location.updated_at': '2020-08-11T12:25:14.690Z',
    'location.created_by': null,
    'location.updated_by': null,
    'location.location_type.id': '732a8981-b9d5-457a-a2ef-2dfafbfec92e',
    'location.location_type.container_id': 'ba1ee2bc-e301-48ce-8b83-9531931c2973',
    'location.location_type.can_have_devices': true,
    'location.location_type.name': 'street',
    'location.location_type.is_address_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.is_location_map_applicable': true,
    'location.location_type.created_at': '2020-08-11T12:24:13.070Z',
    'location.location_type.updated_at': '2020-08-11T12:24:13.070Z',
    'location.location_type.company_id': '4a741eeb-9c56-4b69-88a4-ceca97c13241'
  }
]
```

I want to build a structure like below from the above JSON array

```html
"70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20": {
    "building": [
        "8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d",
        "a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47"
    ],
    "area": [
        "4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93":{
            "dd962969-36ce-416a-a9c7-794cc20fb233"
        }
    ],
}
```

My current code is like below but this doesnt work as expected

```
    let locations = locationsPermissions;

siteKeys = locationsPermissions
  .map((values, idx) => {
    const containerId = values["location.container_id"];
    const locationId = values["location.id"];
    if (containerId === null) {
      locations.splice(idx, 1);
      return locationId;
    } else {
      return;
    }
  })
  .filter((item) => item);

  const sitePermissionDict = {};
    siteKeys.forEach((keys) => {
      let locationObject = {};
      locations.forEach((values) => {
        console.info('&&&&&&&&', values);
        const typeName = values['location.location_type.name'];
        const containerId = values['location.container_id'];
        const locationId = values['location.id'];
        if (locationObject[typeName] == undefined) {
          locationObject[typeName] = [];
        }
        locationObject[typeName] = locationObject[typeName].concat(values.location_id);
        sitePermissionDict[keys] = locationObject;
      });
  });
  return sitePermissionDict;
});
```

And the output of the above code is like below

```
{
    "70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20": {
        "building": [
            "8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d",
            "a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47"
        ],
        "area": [
            "4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93"
        ],
        "street": [
            "dd962969-36ce-416a-a9c7-794cc20fb233"
        ]
    }
}
```

which is supposed to be

```html
"70488413-6750-4f0b-8947-061a85c49e20": {
    "building": [
        "8e0bc18c-0387-49e2-99ea-a6359b60d54d",
        "a014a059-8d43-4337-830c-e2742627cf47"
    ],
    "area": [
        "4ec12e88-64eb-4b0d-bfc7-7a46f562cf93":{
            "dd962969-36ce-416a-a9c7-794cc20fb233"
        }
    ],
}
```

Where all location.container_id = null should be the parent key
and wherever location.id = location.container_id it should be nested inside location.id . is there a optimal way to achieve this ? Please help me as i am completely stuck on this

Comment: What is the code you posted doing, how is it not working as expected?

Comment: @MLarionov edited accordingly

Comment: hey @naveen what is  `locations` in this line of code `locations.splice(idx, 1);`

Comment: @ChintanKotadiya added that . Please review

Comment: Your example output contains data that doesn't exist in the input.  If you want help you're going to have to share an example based on the provided input.  Otherwise it's going to be like cracking a cipher to figure out what you mean, what with all these cryptic hash-like strings.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @naveen I have try and found little bit optimization on that. you can use direct filter function on `locationsPermissions` on that.

```
let locations = locationsPermissions;
const sitePermissionDict = {};

siteKeys = locationsPermissions.filter((values, idx) => {
    const containerId = values["location.container_id"];
    const locationId = values["location.id"];
    if (containerId === null) {
        locations.splice(idx, 1);
        return locationId;
    }
})

siteKeys.forEach((keys) => {
    let locationObject = {};
    locations.forEach((values) => {
        const typeName = values['location.location_type.name'];
        const containerId = values['location.container_id'];
        const locationId = values['location.id'];
        if (locationObject[typeName] == undefined) {
          locationObject[typeName] = [];
        }
        locationObject[typeName] = locationObject[typeName].concat(values.location_id);             
        sitePermissionDict[keys['location.id']] = locationObject;             
    });
});
console.log(sitePermissionDict)
```

Hope that will help. Thanks